# tf.image.resize_images( images, size, method=ResizeMethod.BILINEAR, align_corners=False )

Tags: python, image, tensorflow, image-processing

If the argument size is the same as the dimensions of the original image what happens?

```
img = Image.open(data_dir[it]) 
filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer([data_dir[it]]) 
reader = tf.WholeFileReader()
key, value = reader.read(filename_queue)
my_img = tf.image.decode_jpeg(value, channels = 3) 
print(my_img.shape)
my_img = tf.image.resize_images(my_img,  (img.size[0], img.size[1]), method=1, align_corners = False)
my_img = tf.expand_dims(my_img, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simulating your **desired scenario** in **Tensorflow 2.1.0**, as expected it still returns the same image as the original.

Here is the code used for simulation in **Google Colab Environment**:

```
%tensorflow_version 2.x
import tensorflow as tf
from PIL import Image
import imageio
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

folder_dir = '/content/sample_data/birds/'
data_dir = [folder_dir+'bird1.jpg', folder_dir+'bird2.jpg', folder_dir+'bird3.jpg']

images = []
for it in range(len(data_dir)):
  print("Image Number {}".format(it))
  img = imageio.imread(data_dir[it]) 
  img = img / 255
  print("Original Image Size : {}".format(img.shape))
  my_img = tf.image.resize(img,  (img.shape[0], img.shape[1]), method= 'bilinear')
  print("After Image Resize : {}\n".format(my_img.shape))
  # plt.imshow(my_img)
  # plt.show()
```

After executing this code the **output** is shown below.

```
Image Number 0
Original Image Size : (396, 640, 3)
After Image Resize : (396, 640, 3)

Image Number 1
Original Image Size : (1200, 800, 3)
After Image Resize : (1200, 800, 3)

Image Number 2
Original Image Size : (480, 800, 3)
After Image Resize : (480, 800, 3)
```

*Note: Plots are suppressed to shorten the answer.*

You could read more about **TensorFlow Image Resize** function in this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/resize).